# AngularJS Chosen not working/updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

Two part issue

1. Chosen is not being applied on load to the select items
2. When manually triggering chosen, the filter in ng-options does not apply

The select:

```
<select chosen allow-single-deselect="true" no-results-text="Oops, nothing found!" data-placeholder="SELECT VENUE" id="filter_venue" name="venue" ng-model="venueSelect" ng-options="venue[1] for venue in venues | filter:citySelect">
    <option value="">All Venues</option>
</select>
```

citySelect is another drop-down which works fine without chosen

The drop-down works as needed without chosen

Comment: Tell about your project more...so that we can help you out..

Comment: What do you need to know? Bower is used to install chosen, which was successful. The project was constructed with yeoman. Venues is an array of arrays, where the index 1 contains the data I need. Everything is working except for the functionality provided by chosen.